# Chat mobile com refresh contínuo

Tags: bug, chat, mobile

Ao acessar o chat [estouro de pilha](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) pelo celular, o mesmo fica atualizando automaticamente, impossibilitando assim a utilização.

Estou testando com o Google Chrome v55.0.2883.91.

Isso ocorreu comigo em dois smartphones com o SO Android, que são:

- Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge
- Motorola Moto Z Play

Segue abaixo o que está ocorrendo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acabei de testar no moto z play e não ocorreu este problema.

Comment: Atualizando automaticamente como assim?

Comment: @JorgeB. Toda vez que acesso e termina de carregar, e atualiza a página novamente, como o F5

Comment: @JorgeB. Irei tentar gravar a tela para melhor demonstrar aqui, um min

Comment: @Randrade estou a com a mesma versão do chrome e está a funcionar direito no [Cubot Manito](http://www.cubot.net/smartphones/manito/).

Comment: @JorgeB. Adicionei o GIF. Eu disse errado, ocorre quando estou deslogado.

Comment: @diegofm Eu disse errado, ocorre quando estou deslogado.

Comment: @Randrade mesmo sem login funciona direito.

Comment: Apenas uma duvida, por paz de espirito, tentou abrir o chat deslogado em modo anonimo (incognito)?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Em modo anônimo não ocorre (isso deslogado). Logado eu não testei ainda

Comment: @Randrade uma vez me ocorreu isso, acredito que foi durante uma atualização (build ... algo assim, não sei como a SO faz a atualização das funcionalidades/correções) e isto conflitou com o cache+alguma chat armazenada em cookie ou localStorage, só limpando os dados eu consegui voltar a usar.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Limpei os dados do cache/cookies/etc. E até instalei o Chrome Beta/Dev e continuou da mesma forma :/

Comment: @Randrade que estranho, deve ser um BUG mesmo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento O pior que está acontecendo somente comigo.

Comment: @Randrade estranho que em modo anonimo funcionou, foi o que eu entendi. Pode ser que o teu Android/Chrome sejam mais atualizados e seja um conflito de script (um bug mesmo) e em versões mais antigas esteja normal. Eu não uso android, mas vou testar o emulador para termos uma noção.

Comment: O meu celular, Um moto Z começou a apresentar um problema semelhante, ele não da refresh continuou porém aparece a mensagem que tenho que ficar logado para conectar, após isso preciso fechar o finalizar a aba e o navegador no celular e abrir novamente para funcionar